# How computational expensive is running JavaScript inside an instance of a web browser

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a circuit maker program and designing my own scripts using the JavaScript commands that the program allows. However, the program also allows us to use HTML, meaning that an instance of the web browser will be open each time that the user needs to, say, insert values into a dynamicaly changing table. 
I do not know anything about Javascript or HTML so I was wondering if going through through the web browser would slow down the program. 
Thank you kindly

Comment: HTML is just a markup language. It's not required to use it in the browser - you could use it in a similar fashion as XML, or any other markup language. The browser is simply something that translates HTML into a nice view.

Comment: Okay. I'm confused, then, because the documentation of my program says, "JavaScript is running inside an instance of Internet Explorer," . Doesn't that meant that it needs a browser?

Comment: You haven't given us any information about your chip or your program.

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry. The program is a circut schematic program that allows one to make scripts to customizedevices such as resistors, capacitors, etc.

Comment: I meant: you are referencing documentation. Where is it? What is it for? Can we see it?

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be read by someone who doesn't have the document. The circuit schematic is called DesignWorks

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a language for browsers first. During a run of almost each page in web executes very big pack of JS. Also js can compile with browser compilators like jit . Thats why no - js running is not expensive in browser. If your programm is not image recognition (for example), of course. But browser open - it may be slow operation.